# Include php files only when needed at runtime

Tags: php

I have some PHP code which looks roughly like this

```
require_once 'cache.php';
require_once 'generator.php';

if (cache_dirty ('foo')) {
    cache_update ('foo', generate_foo ());
}

print cache_read ('foo');
```

My problem is that `generator.php` includes a whole mass of libraries and I don't want to load/parse it unless `cache_dirty` actually returns `false` at runtime.

I know there are PHP precompilers which can help but for now I need a quick fix. Is this possible?

Comment: Look into [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) your stuff.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning autoloading, that is certainly the right long-term solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require_once 'cache.php';

if (cache_dirty ('foo')) {
    require_once 'generator.php';
    cache_update ('foo', generate_foo ());
}

print cache_read ('foo');
```

Fits your question quite well ...

Answer (score 5):

As PeeHaa already said in his comment, [Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) is usually the ideal way to go (although it will require restructuring your app.)

However, in the situation you show, I'm not sure what's keeping you from doing

```
require_once 'cache.php';


if (cache_dirty ('foo')) {
     require_once 'generator.php';
     cache_update ('foo', generate_foo ());

}
```

?

Answer (score 2):

You should write a PHP `__autoload` function to dynamically require `generator.php` when a `generate_foo` call is found.

Answer (score 1):

Just include / require `generator.php` in the `if` block.  Also, you shouldn't have a space between your function names and `(` in function calls.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is OO (object oriented), you should be using PHP's `__autoload()` feature.

Otherwise, just use conditional `require_once()`s.